# MySQL CRM database dilemma

Tags: php, mysql, database, relational-database, crm

I'm working on making a consumer CRM system for my boot-strapped startup, where we'll use MySQL. We're moving from an old paper and pen method of tracking leads and referrals, to a digital method for our dealers.

The database will have a standard fields, like lead name, spouse, jobs, referral type, referrer, and lead dealer. This is easy, almost child's play.

Now is the part I'm having a hard time figuring it out. I want to track all the attempted contact dates and responses, and appointments that have been set or reset. The system is going to be web-based, with the front-end in PHP.

I thought about doing nested tables, but I don't want to use Oracle or PostgreSQL, as I like the familiar setup of MySQL.

For the sake of feasibility, say I have 4,000 leads, and each lead is going to be called on average 30 times. So I'll have 120,000 data points to track.

Would it be advisable to:

1. Make a two dimensional PHP array in the field, to keep track of these metrics.
2. Have a contact table with all 120k in it, that the application pulls when these metrics are needed
3. Have a contact table for each lead, which keeps track of all needed metrics

Comment: This is not programming advice, but entrepreneurial: if you're bootstrapping in a start-up, don't waste time building a CRM--use Sugar, or Salseforce, or something. Your time is too valuable. If not, you probably should figure out a different busniess.

Comment: For our needs neither Sugar, Salesforce, or any of their competition has the features that we require. So for now, on my weekend, I've taken the time to work on a CRM. I've got most of what I need, except this problem, solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make one table for contacts.  Add a column to record whether the contact was successful or not.

I would also use MySQL's [table partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html) by lead, if many of the queries will be to report on specific leads.

---

But I second the comment from @Bryan Agee that you should consider carefully before implementing a CRM system from scratch on your weekends.

Comment: This was actually the way I ended up going. I left that project the following May, so I'm unaware if it was ever finished. But I did want to thank you for the answer, from 5 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the table of just the leads. Ideally, it should be filterable and searchable and sortable. Look into the [jquery datatables plugin](http://www.datatables.net/). You can have a table that's paged and pulls its data using AJAX from the server. That way you only need to query and return a few records at a time.

Then create a second table that pops up when the user clicks on the contact. This one is also AJAX and displays the contact history for that particular contact.

This way you never have to query and return the full list, especially if you have 4000, which would be a pain not only for the server but for the people using the system.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is pretty much what has been done, but it doesn't solve the dilemma of tracking the attempted contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Have a contact table for each lead, and add data to it every time action(Contact) is made. It will also give you count and other metrics and it will be easy to implement and track.